# Switching from node-sass to dart-sass in vue-styleguidist project

Tags: vue.js, sass, dart-sass, vue-styleguidist

The project uses node-sass but I'd like to switch to dart-sass since node-sass is deprecated.

If I uninstall node-sass and install sass I get the following error:

```
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass. Run 'npm install node-sass' or 'yarn add node-sass' inside your workspace
```

In case I uninstall node-sass and install sass in node-sass wrapper (npm install --save-dev node-sass@npm:sass) the project compiles successfully. What is the way to get it to work with pure sass installed?

So the goal is to have "sass": "^1.38.0" in the devDependencies instead of "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.38.0"

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade of sass-loader to 7.3.1 helped to fix it. So the devDependencies are:

```
"sass": "^1.38.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.3.1"
```

Comment: Thank you - adding the sass-loader turned out to be my issue